# how to enable and use mat-error withough using form control

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ngModel and I wanted to use mat-error but it does not work if you don't use form, is there some hack to it?  that we can use the mat-error with the ngModel.

#code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill"  class="w-48per">
    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="territoryAssignmentFields.repmFirstName" name="repmFirstName" 
    matInput placeholder="" autocomplete="activityNumber">
    <!-- <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper custom-mat-error" >
        <div class="mat-error" >Required</div>                        
      </div>
    <div id="repmFirstNameRequiredError"></div>   -->
    <mat-error >My error message</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: doing this is far easier if you do reactive form, let me know if you need help in writing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `template variable` in your input and use that in `mat-error`.

```
#nameCtrl="ngModel"
```

You can use above variable in your `mat-error` like this:-

```
<mat-error *ngIf="nameCtrl.hasError('required')">required</mat-error>
```

Complete Sample code:-

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill"  class="w-48per">
    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="territoryAssignmentFields.repmFirstName" name="repmFirstName"  #nameCtrl="ngModel" 
    matInput placeholder="" autocomplete="activityNumber">

    <mat-error *ngIf="nameCtrl.hasError('required')">required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```